# How to resize plotly graph on child layout of PyQt5 Application

Tags: python, pyqt5, plotly

I would like to adjust my plotly graphic with child layout  which contains it and it will be perfect to see it automatically resize along with the window
[Would like see such configuration of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wgz8.jpg)

I have the follow objects in my .ui file:
[.ui inspector object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn73C.jpg)

My beginning of code:

```
    class MainWindow(QWidget, From_Main):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)
       
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.browser)
```

Code for plotter functione:

```
    def plotter(self):
        df_period = self.all_data.loc[:len(self.all_data)-13]
        df_predict = self.all_data.loc[len(self.all_data)-12:]
        fig = go.Figure()
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_period.index, y=df_period['value'], mode='lines', name='value'))
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_predict.index, y=df_predict['value'], mode='lines', opacity=0.7, name='value_true'))
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_predict.index, y=df_predict['value_predict'], mode='lines',  name='value_predict'))
        self.browser.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
```